# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> using pow

Tags: python, series, pow

I have dataframe and I want to calculate 10^(0.13*df['value']) for every row and save results to new column.

df:

value  |  value2

---

22
12
22
33

I want in column value2 save results for example: 10^(-0.13*22) for first row.

I tried:

### import math

df['value2'] = math.pow(10, -0.13*df['value'])

Type error: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the python function math.pow expect the second argument to be of type float, since you want to calculate the power for every element in your serie, you should use the numpy packag, so may be try

```
import numpy as np
np.power(10, -13 * df['value'])
```